# Objective-C dynamically created methods and compiler warnings

Tags: objective-c, metaprogramming, objective-c-runtime

If I generate methods dynamically on runtime and then call them - how can I convince compiler that the class will respond to undeclared (generated) methods and make it not throw warnings?

**Update in regard to answers**

When I generate the methods - their name is not known at compile time. To give an example - if I have a view controller `MyFooController` and it's initiated with method `initWithFoo:(Foo*)foo`, I'd be able to generate method like `pushMyFooControllerWithFoo:(Foo *)foo` for `UINavigationController`. Hence you notice that declaring such methods would be counter-productive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but if I was generating method names (presumably from strings), I would call them using the string names, hence bypassing the compiler warnings.

```
[fooController performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"pushMyFooControllerWithFoo:") withObject:foo];
```

That way you are responsible for the validity of the generated method names.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are adding methods on runtime, so you should also invoke them with runtime function, `objc_msgSend` or `performSelector:withObject:`for example, so the compiler will not going to warn you anything.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you call them, you know their signature, and if you know their signature, you can declare them, can't you?

Comment: Your update doesn't seem enough. *if you can call* them, you can declare them. So show us how you call them, so we can understand

Comment: The fact that a method is called does not imply the knowledge of the signature at compile time and therefore it does not imply the declarability of this method.

Comment: You are right of course. But the OP says there is a warning from the compiler.  I don't see why the OP asks about how to get rid of a warning without letting us know which warning, and on which source code line. What's the point of withholding that information? It might very well be relevant.

Comment: Indeed the question would be much less misleading with this information. Nevertheless the question _“how can I convince compiler that the class will respond to undeclared (generated) methods and make it not throw warnings?”_ gives the hint that the warning is about undeclared methods (e.g. foo may not respond to bar).

Answer (score 0):

Declare this method in a category for NSObject and make an empty implementation:

```
@interface NSObject (DynamicMethodsCategory)

- (void)doSomething;

@end

@implementation NSObject (DynamicMethodsCategory)

- (void)doSomething
{
}

@end
```

In your object you can call it without any warnings:

```
@implementation MyObject

- (void)someMethod
{
    [self doSomething];
}

@end
```

Then generate implementation of `[MyObject doSomething]` dynamically, it will be called instead of `NSObject's` one.

Update:
Alternatively, the method can be declared in a category for the object. This suppresses the compiler's *Incomplete implementation* warning. However, I think this is not a good workaround, because the application will crash if the method is not created dynamically in runtime before it is called.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have updated a question with more details. Looking forward to your ideas .)

Comment: So, do you know the name of the method at compile time or not? If not, how can you make the compiler to warn you?